# Multi series Highcharts not plotting graph , json format?

Tags: json, database, highcharts

Im trying to get some database temperture values to plot inside a graph , But it seems the json format is not right for it to render ,(maybe something with the quotes?) but cant seem to fix the problem , any help would pointing in the right direction would be greatly appriciated .

Would love to see the date/time data plotted on the xasis as well

Here is my code 
html graph

> ```
>    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
> ```
>
> Groendak
>
> ```
>    <script type="text/javascript"   
>     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
>    <script type="text/javascript">
> ```
>
> $(function () {
>      var chart;
>      $(document).ready(function() {
>          $.getJSON("data3.php", function(json) {
>
> ```
>        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
>            chart: {
>               renderTo: 'container',  
>              type: 'line',
>                marginRight: 130,
>                marginBottom: 25
>            },
>            title: {
>                text: 'Sensor1 vs. Sensor2',
>                x: -20 //center
>            },
>            subtitle: {
>                text: '',
>                x: -20
>            },
>            xAxis: {
>
>
>    },
>           yAxis: {
>                title: {
>                    text: 'Temperatuur'
>                },
>                plotLines: [{
>                    value: 0,
>                    width: 1,
>                    color: '#808080'
>                }]
>            },
>            tooltip: {
>                formatter: function() {
>                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
>                        this.x +': '+ this.y;
>                }
>            },
>            legend: {
>                layout: 'vertical',
>                align: 'right',
>                verticalAlign: 'top',
>                x: -10,
>                y: 100,
>                borderWidth: 0
>            },
>            series: json
>        });
>    });
> ```
>
> });
>
> });

The data3.php part

> `$series3['data'][] = $r['sensor10'];   
> $series4['data'][] = $r['time'];`   
>
>   
>   }
>   
>   $result = array();
>   array_push($result,$category);
>   
>   array_push($result,$series1);
>   
>   array_push($result,$series3);
>   array_push($result,$series4);
>   
>   print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
>   
>   mysql_close($con);
>   ?>

and the json data that i get from the data3.php

```
    [{"name":"sensor1","data":[" 245 "," 245 "," 286 "," 289 "," 292 "," 290 "," 289 "," 287 "," 288 "," 286 "," 281 "," 279 "," 280 "," 277 "," 272 "," 270 "," 270 "," 267 "," 265 "," 264 "," 263 "," 260 "," 258 "," 259 "," 258 "," 257 "," 255 "," 252 "," 251 "," 252 "," 248 "," 247 "," 245 "," 244 "," 241 "," 239 "," 241 "," 237 "," 238 "," 234 "," 235 "," 234 "," 232 "," 230 "," 229 "," 230 "," 228 "," 228 "," 228 "," 227 "," 225 "," 226 "," 224 "," 225 "," 224 "," 223 "," 220 "," 220 "," 222 "," 222 "," 218 "," 220 "," 220 "," 218 "," 219 "," 218 "," 217 "," 219 "," 218 "," 216 "," 218 "," 215 "," 217 "," 218 "," 214 "," 216 "," 214 "," 214 "," 217 "," 214 "," 215 "," 214 "," 216 "," 215 "," 214 "," 217 "," 215 "," 215 "," 215 "," 216 "," 218 "," 217 "," 218 "," 219 "," 219 "," 221 "," 220 "," 221 "," 224 "," 225 "," 224 "," 226 "," 225 "," 228 "," 229 "," 229 "," 231 "," 230 "," 230 "," 231 "," 232 "]},{"name":"sensor2","data":[" 313 "," 312 "," 291 "," 285 "," 277 "," 278 "," 273 "," 271 "," 266 "," 261 "," 261 "," 258 "," 251 "," 249 "," 251 "," 249 "," 245 "," 243 "," 243 "," 239 "," 237 "," 239 "," 238 "," 232 "," 230 "," 229 "," 229 "," 230 "," 229 "," 223 "," 225 "," 222 "," 220 "," 217 "," 219 "," 219 "," 212 "," 216 "," 210 "," 214 "," 209 "," 209 "," 209 "," 210 "," 209 "," 206 "," 206 "," 204 "," 202 "," 202 "," 204 "," 199 "," 200 "," 197 "," 195 "," 196 "," 199 "," 198 "," 193 "," 192 "," 197 "," 193 "," 192 "," 195 "," 192 "," 194 "," 195 "," 191 "," 191 "," 193 "," 191 "," 196 "," 192 "," 193 "," 198 "," 196 "," 200 "," 200 "," 199 "," 204 "," 204 "," 208 "," 206 "," 209 "," 214 "," 211 "," 218 "," 221 "," 224 "," 227 "," 228 "," 233 "," 236 "," 239 "," 244 "," 248 "," 252 "," 255 "," 255 "," 258 "," 266 "," 266 "," 273 "," 271 "," 273 "," 278 "," 279 "," 284 "," 288 "," 291 "," 291 "]},{"name":"sensor10","data":[" 240 "," 178 "," 187 "," 198 "," 201 "," 204 "," 203 "," 189 "," 186 "," 188 "," 191 "," 193 "," 195 "," 203 "," 198 "," 196 "," 196 "," 196 "," 195 "," 196 "," 196 "," 197 "," 196 "," 193 "," 190 "," 192 "," 194 "," 194 "," 194 "," 189 "," 183 "," 180 "," 180 "," 180 "," 180 "," 178 "," 177 "," 180 "," 182 "," 184 "," 184 "," 184 "," 184 "," 184 "," 183 "," 183 "," 182 "," 182 "," 180 "," 182 "," 181 "," 180 "," 180 "," 180 "," 180 "," 182 "," 182 "," 182 "," 181 "," 183 "," 183 "," 182 "," 182 "," 181 "," 181 "," 182 "," 183 "," 184 "," 185 "," 186 "," 186 "," 188 "," 191 "," 199 "," 202 "," 200 "," 202 "," 203 "," 209 "," 206 "," 210 "," 210 "," 206 "," 214 "," 224 "," 234 "," 235 "," 238 "," 232 "," 247 "," 276 "," 277 "," 255 "," 243 "," 242 "," 257 "," 242 "," 254 "," 258 "," 269 "," 264 "," 265 "," 254 "," 263 "," 278 "," 277 "," 259 "," 259 "," 266 "," 278 "," 284 "]},{"name":"time","data":[" 2014-07-10 19:26:52"," 2014-07-10 19:36:52"," 2014-07-10 19:46:52"," 2014-07-10 19:56:52"," 2014-07-10 20:06:52"," 2014-07-10 20:16:52"," 2014-07-10 20:26:52"," 2014-07-10 20:36:52"," 2014-07-10 20:46:52"," 2014-07-10 20:56:52"," 2014-07-10 21:06:52"," 2014-07-10 21:16:52"," 2014-07-10 21:26:52"," 2014-07-10 21:36:53"," 2014-07-10 21:46:53"," 2014-07-10 21:56:53"," 2014-07-10 22:06:53"," 2014-07-10 22:16:53"," 2014-07-10 22:26:53"," 2014-07-10 22:36:53"," 2014-07-10 22:46:53"," 2014-07-10 22:56:53"," 2014-07-10 23:06:53"," 2014-07-10 23:16:54"," 2014-07-10 23:26:54"," 2014-07-10 23:36:54"," 2014-07-10 23:46:54"," 2014-07-10 23:56:54"," 2014-07-11 00:06:54"," 2014-07-11 00:16:54"," 2014-07-11 00:26:54"," 2014-07-11 00:36:54"," 2014-07-11 00:46:54"," 2014-07-11 00:56:54"," 2014-07-11 01:06:54"," 2014-07-11 01:16:54"," 2014-07-11 01:26:54"," 2014-07-11 01:36:55"," 2014-07-11 01:46:55"," 2014-07-11 01:56:55"," 2014-07-11 02:06:55"," 2014-07-11 02:16:55"," 2014-07-11 02:26:55"," 2014-07-11 02:36:55"," 2014-07-11 02:46:55"," 2014-07-11 02:56:55"," 2014-07-11 03:06:55"," 2014-07-11 03:16:55"," 2014-07-11 03:26:56"," 2014-07-11 03:36:56"," 2014-07-11 03:46:56"," 2014-07-11 03:56:56"," 2014-07-11 04:06:56"," 2014-07-11 04:16:56"," 2014-07-11 04:26:56"," 2014-07-11 04:36:56"," 2014-07-11 04:46:56"," 2014-07-11 04:56:56"," 2014-07-11 05:06:56"," 2014-07-11 05:16:56"," 2014-07-11 05:26:56"," 2014-07-11 05:36:56"," 2014-07-11 05:46:56"," 2014-07-11 05:56:57"," 2014-07-11 06:06:57"," 2014-07-11 06:16:57"," 2014-07-11 06:26:57"," 2014-07-11 06:36:57"," 2014-07-11 06:46:57"," 2014-07-11 06:56:57"," 2014-07-11 07:06:57"," 2014-07-11 07:16:57"," 2014-07-11 07:26:57"," 2014-07-11 07:36:57"," 2014-07-11 07:46:57"," 2014-07-11 07:56:58"," 2014-07-11 08:06:58"," 2014-07-11 08:16:58"," 2014-07-11 08:26:58"," 2014-07-11 08:36:58"," 2014-07-11 08:46:58"," 2014-07-11 08:56:58"," 2014-07-11 09:06:58"," 2014-07-11 09:16:58"," 2014-07-11 09:26:58"," 2014-07-11 09:36:58"," 2014-07-11 09:46:58"," 2014-07-11 09:56:58"," 2014-07-11 10:06:58"," 2014-07-11 10:16:58"," 2014-07-11 10:26:59"," 2014-07-11 10:36:59"," 2014-07-11 10:46:59"," 2014-07-11 10:56:59"," 2014-07-11 11:06:59"," 2014-07-11 11:16:59"," 2014-07-11 11:26:59"," 2014-07-11 11:36:59"," 2014-07-11 11:46:59"," 2014-07-11 11:56:59"," 2014-07-11 12:07:00"," 2014-07-11 12:17:00"," 2014-07-11 12:27:00"," 2014-07-11 12:37:00"," 2014-07-11 12:47:00"," 2014-07-11 12:57:00"," 2014-07-11 13:07:00"," 2014-07-11 13:17:00"," 2014-07-11 13:27:00"," 2014-07-11 13:37:00"," 2014-07-11 13:47:00"]}]
```

the parser

> ```
>    <?php
> ```
>
> $con = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', 'xxxxx' );
>
> if (!$con) {
>     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
>   }
>
> mysql_select_db("groendak", $con);
>
> $query = mysql_query("SELECT sensor1, sensor2, sensor10, time FROM opstelling1");
>
> $category = array();
>   $category['name'] = 'sensor1';
>
> $series1 = array();
>   $series1['name'] = 'sensor2';
>
> $series3 = array();
>   $series3['name'] = 'Buiten Lucht';
>
> $series4 = array();
>   $series4['name'] = 'time';
>
> while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
>       $category['data'][] = intval($r['sensor1']);
>       $series1['data'][] = intval($r['sensor2']);
>       $series3['data'][] = intval($r['sensor10']);
>       $series4['data'][] = 1000.0*strtotime($r['time']);
>   }
>
> $result = array();
>   array_push($result,$category);
>   array_push($result,$series1);
>   array_push($result,$series3);
>   array_push($result,$series4);
>
> print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
>
> mysql_close($con);
>   ?>

Comment: To anwser my own question ,  the solution was to use intval to make the string into an int value with the folowing code
$category['data'][] = intval( $r['sensor1']);
this make the json return a [234, 234] format and not the ["234"," 234"] . making the line plot

Comment: In the json_encode() you can also set a JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK.

Comment: yes i have done that with no result. the intval did the trick . 
but now im having trouble to get the date on the x-axis . Think it has to do with the way the data is formated from the data3.php --json 
Would love some help with that

Comment: So now, how your json looks like, is parsed correct?

Comment: now it looks like this ,
[{"name":"sensor1","data":[245,245,286,289,292,290,289,287]},
{"name":"sensor2","data":[313,312,291,285,277,278,273,271]},
{"name":"time","data":[" 2014-07-10 19:26:52"," 2014-07-10 19:36:52"," 2014-07-10 19:46:52"]}]   

off course with allot more data inside , but in that format 
still have not found a way to put the time/date on the xas in the right format , something with converting the format i read somewhere but cant implement it . Thanks for your help

Comment: Please check how json should look like, you cannot have a dates in the series data. If these dates should be on the xAxis, you need to parser your json to correct form (I mean puth your dates to categoreis on xAxis) and other values to series.data

Comment: By any chance you can supply me with a sample of how that should look like ?

Comment: Json is the final format right ? and the parser the php that does the job ? . then ill say the parser :p . . cant seem to write the php code inside here ( i have put it above)

Comment: We support HS solutions, not prepareing code in the PHP.

Comment: sorry but i dont understand what you mean by HS solutions.  Please explain , and thanks for taking the time to explain , realy apriciate it

Comment: I mean that we help with highcharts products not with php solutions and knowledge related with prepareing array in php.

Comment: ok , But you cant give me a hint on how the final json should look like for it to work with the highchart ? i mean how will the data have to be organized to display the date on the xas , what your calling the catagorie
or does the jason need like { date , reading1 ,reading 2 etc},{ date , reading1 ,reading 2 etc}, and again ?

Comment: The json needs to looks like series array here: http://jsfiddle.net/2uc9k/

Comment: ok , but im seeing the line series :json does indeed put the data in json format like the example you send , but i still dont understand how to get the timedata on the different axis , do i have to make a new json to het only the time data into the catagories ?  and how would the catagorie data be formated within the same json that has the data ? thanks allot mate

Comment: Anyone care to look at my graph and tell me why i cant get the time/date on the xasis  ?? . my grap can be found at www.ice-control/stock/index.html
thanks in advance

Comment: Your website seems to be down.

Comment: sorry , forgot the .nl so its 
www.ice-control.nl/stock/index.html

Comment: In case when you set x as 0,1,2,3.... etc which are miliseconds, it is returned correctly. You should have a dates (timestamps) not 1,2,3,4...

Comment: i think i understand what you mean , but dont know how to implement it , any chance you can give me an example php to set that up so the timestamp gets in the place of the 1,2 ,3 ? Im a noobie with the javascript , php

Comment: But 1 is which date, 2 is which date? which is range between points?

Comment: the points are 10 minuts appart , first point is 2014-07-10 19:26:52 the second one is 2014-07-10 19:36:52 etc . thanks for your great help with the graph

Comment: So you need to parse this dates in php to unix timestamp and multiply by 1000,then you achive correct form.

Comment: isnt that what im already doing by $series4['data'][] = (1000*strtotime( $r['time']));  . i thouth i did it correctly , but im not getting the expected result , cause now the date of 2014-07-10 19:26:52 returns 1405013212000 wich is the unix timestamp * 1000 right ? or am i seeing the whole thing wrong ?

Comment: It is correct way, but your timestmaps doesnt exist in your series obejct. Please attach your json, which is print in this line: print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

Comment: http://www.ice-control.nl/stock/data11.php  should give you the json like its generated from the php, ( i tried to put it above but it gets modified to unreadable )

Comment: Its wrong, because you should have data points as pairs [x,y] not x as  one data array, and y as other series. In other wrods, each points should look like this: [1405013212000,245]

Comment: so you mean something like [1405013212000 , 259 , 263 , 251]and then the rest in the same way ?

Comment: Eeach point need to be pair, like here: http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?, each point is [timestamp, yValue] in each serie.

Comment: ok , so more like this http://www.ice-control.nl/stock/data12.php
and then with the right [] closing each dataset right ? Ill have to go figure out how to complete that then , also the " in the datapoints needs to be removed right ?

Comment: Please see my earlier answer again. series: [{data:[[1405013212000,245],[1405013212000,245]]},{data:[[1405013212000,245],[1405013212000,245]]},{data:[[1405013212000,245],[1405013212000,245]]}]

Comment: ok , i will try myself for some to get it right , ill post in here again after some time to let know if it worked ( have to go away for a few) . thanks allot for your help , just in case your wondering , its a school project that im working on , plotting temp data of taken of a green roof at different point in the structure ( suppose to see the temp buildup ) but thanks , ill keep you posted

Comment: ok, so im still having trouble plotting the graph , the data seems to be in the right format now but the graph is not plotting anymore ,any chance you can point me in the right direction ??
hmtl page found here .http://www.ice-control.nl/stock/opstelling1.html

data thats get generated lloks like this http://www.ice-control.nl/stock/data.php

and the php parser that creates the json looks like this 
http://www.ice-control.nl/stock/dataphp.txt

hope you can help me out here to make it work < thanks

Comment: Well, the problem is that you mean that array ( $arr[] = 'text') and $arr = "['text']" is the same, but is not the same. So please focus on php and check how to create arrays.

Comment: would be nice if you can tell me if the first or the second one is the one i should use , ( im an absolute newbie with php and espesialy json) sorry for so many questions, a good php example would help me allot if you can

Comment: You need to use first one, See the manuals of php to know php syntax.

Comment: ive tried this one . www.ice-control.nl/stock/data111.php but seems to still not be working , the php file can be found here www.ice-control.nl/stock/data111php.txt  
would you be so kind to show me the correct php syntax. seems like i just cant get it right , trust me ive been trying all sort of things and reading alot , but its difficult , would realy realy realy apriciate if you could show me how the php should go for it to work correctly

Comment: Honestly I cannot learn you how to use PHP, I point you in many direcitosn, but all is up to you. You need to create arrays scturture and parse it.

Comment: sebastian , is it possible to pay to for you to make the necesary php and javascript for my problem ?. Thanks

Comment: Well I think that we point you in many directions, which should solve your issue. Please familiar with the createing arrays in php.

Comment: i greatly apriciate your help, but im running short on time and need it working , thats why the pay question , would be verry helpfull , pay in btc ? sure it wont take allot of time to complete.any way to contact you directky ?

Comment: Please contact with us by support@highcharts.com with entire spec.

Comment: Thanks , i just sended a mail. Hope to hear soon